# Strip lines added to ChartArea, but never displayed on Chart

Tags: .net, mschart

I'm trying to get StripLines to display on a chart I've put together, but so far I've had no joy in getting them to display at all.

```
    Public Sub AddExtraChartData(ByVal fromTime As DateTime, ByVal toTime As DateTime)
    ' create a background strip line for any records held within here
    Dim sl As New Charting.StripLine()

    sl.IntervalOffset = fromTime.ToOADate()
    sl.IntervalOffsetType = Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes
    Console.WriteLine("strip_interval_offset: " + sl.IntervalOffset.ToString())

    sl.BackColor = Color.Red
    sl.StripWidth = toTime.ToOADate() - fromTime.ToOADate()

    Console.WriteLine("Length of downtime: " + sl.StripWidth.ToString())
    sl.StripWidthType = Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes

    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.StripLines.Add(sl)

    Console.WriteLine("Strip Line Count in Chart1.ChartAreas(0): ?" + Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.StripLines.Count.ToString())

    Chart1.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

It should show them in 'chunks' of time (for machine downtime reporting), at the intervals passed, but nothing ever displays, other than the graph itself. Am I correct in thinking, that if a stripline is added outside of the original bounds the chart would rescale to display it? Or would it be lost?

According to my VS debugging:

```
strip_interval_offset: 41493.4617361111
Length of downtime: 0.0181250000023283
Strip Line Count in Chart1.ChartAreas(0): ?5
```

So they're being added. As I can remove the .Add() and end up with 0. But why won't they display?

Other info. My chart is DateTime format, at 10 minute intervals and XValue is indexed (to display times of innactivity as gaps)

Any help very much appreciated, thanks.